# Ionic 3 OneSignal Push Notification Click Open Page

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, onesignal

I use OneSignal Push Notification for Ionic 3 . I want to when click notification application open page.

> My app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal';


import { DuyurularPage } from '../pages/duyurular/duyurular';

@Component({
 templateUrl: 'app.html',
 providers:[OneSignal],
 template: '<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'

})
export class MyApp {
 rootPage:any = 'MenuPage';
 bgColor: string = '#fff';
 @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController;

constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
SplashScreen, private oneSignal: OneSignal,) {
  platform.ready().then(() => {

   statusBar.styleDefault();
   splashScreen.hide();

   window["plugins"].OneSignal
  .startInit("**************", "***********")
  .handleNotificationOpened()
  .handleNotificationReceived()
  .endInit();
  });

  this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((jsonData) => {
   alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
   this.nav.push(DuyurularPage);
  });
  this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe((jsonData) => 
  {
   alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
   this.nav.push(DuyurularPage);
  });
 }
```

}

When I do mistake I don' t know. Notification coming but not show alert or not push DuyurularPage, just open homepage.

---

Answer (score 1):

if you Need to Open a Specific page on Notification Tapped. Follow the technique.
In App.component.ts

```
          this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((data) => {
            // do something when a notification is opened
            console.log('Tapped',data);
             if(data.notification.payload.additionalData.landing_page != undefined && data.notification.payload.additionalData.landing_page != ''){
               this.PushProvider.landing_page = data.notification.payload.additionalData.landing_page;
             }
             if(data.notification.payload.additionalData.product_id != undefined && data.notification.payload.additionalData.product_id != ''){
               this.PushProvider.product_id = data.notification.payload.additionalData.product_id;
             } 
          });
          this.oneSignal.endInit();
```

//On Home Page

```
  if(this.PushProvider.landing_page != undefined){
      console.log('on home if',this.PushProvider.landing_page);
      this.navCtrl.push('offerzonePage',{ from_tab: this.PushProvider.landing_page});
    }
    if(this.PushProvider.product_id != undefined){
      console.log('on home if',this.PushProvider.product_id);
      this.navCtrl.push('ProductPage',{ product_id: this.PushProvider.product_id });
    }
```

On Pushprovicer.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
@Injectable()
export class PushProvider {


   // Produc ID
   product_id: any;

   // Landing pages
   landing_page: any;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use the below syntax and try;

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal';


import { DuyurularPage } from '../pages/duyurular/duyurular';

@Component({
 templateUrl: 'app.html',
 providers:[OneSignal],
 template: '<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'

})
export class MyApp {
 rootPage:any = 'MenuPage';
 bgColor: string = '#fff';
 @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController;

constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
SplashScreen, private oneSignal: OneSignal,) {
  platform.ready().then(() => {

   statusBar.styleDefault();
   splashScreen.hide();

  this.oneSignal.startInit('*****', '***');
  this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);

  this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((jsonData) => {
   alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
   this.nav.push(DuyurularPage);
  });
  this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe((jsonData) => 
  {
   alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

  });
 }
```

You cannot use `NavController` in `app.component.ts` it seems.

Can you use [Nav](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/Nav/)  or [App](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/app/App/)

Comment: I believe that you cannot just push some page inside the notification receive section, by using navController

Comment: Just have a look at this https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/269

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create an `obsevable` and subscribe to it anywhere needed in my app. The observable will emit its `next` value whenever the plugin callback is fired.

- RxJS Observable
- Emit next value on callback
- Subscribe anywhere in your app
- Use provided NavCtrl to push a component into the view

The same principle would work if you inject ionic's `Event`.

*Btw you have a random comma at the end of your constructor*